# How to open outline/shadowsocks server on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, port, vpn, outline

I made one VM on Microsoft Azure on Linux. Then I connected to it, installed outline-server. But in outline manager it says that, maybe ports are closed. I went to portal.azure.com, made new rule for ports, which are used in Outline, but even with this, i can't make it. Could someone help me?

Comment: you must be getting some error, please post that error as that will help solve the problem

Comment: I'm also puzzled by this problem. I setup a server 2 or 3 months ago in HK and its working well. But this month, when I tried to setup more servers in both HK and Korea regions, I can't get them work. The setup is all the same, ports are open, etc. Is anyone experience this too?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step by step [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/hadisfr/b106dc9d0306cf7630e5b321f27ce8f3) that you can follow to install Outline Server. You may need to [Allow Incoming Connections in Firewall](https://gist.github.com/hadisfr/b106dc9d0306cf7630e5b321f27ce8f3#allow-incoming-connections-in-firewall) and [enable the ports in the network security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal#create-an-inbound-security-rule) of the VM subnet and interface NIC. You can check the NSG setting from virtual machine---networking---inbound port rules.

Let me know if there is an error message on your side.